# xpath with multiple predicates not giving right value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, docbook

I am parsing some DocBook xml to convert to our internal format.

In processing a tgroup element like the following:

```
      <tgroup cols="4">
        <colspec colwidth="1*" />
        <colspec colwidth="1*" />
        <colspec colwidth="1*" />
        <colspec colwidth="1*" />
```

If a given tgroup's col attribute value matches exactly the number of child colspec elements AND there is a colwidth attribute for that colspec, i want to use the colwidth value in the colspec element in the result tree.

My check and the code is as follows:

```
<xsl:when test="(@cols = count(./colspec)) and (./colspec[@colwidth][$number])">

   <colspec>
      <xsl:attribute name="colnum">
           <xsl:value-of select="$number"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="colname">
       <xsl:value-of select="$number"/>
  </xsl:attribute>


  <xsl:attribute name="colwidth">
       <xsl:value-of select="./colspec[@colwidth][$number]"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</colspec>
```

($number is the number of the current colspec being processed.) Instead of getting the colwidth of 1*, i just get

```
coldwidth=""
```

Do i need to specify that i want the attribute value?

I always get kind of tripped up on the xpath expressions, any help any one can provide is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Russ

Comment: What is the current node when you are executing the `<xsl:when>`?  For your example, what is your desired XML output?

Comment: In this case the current node is the tgroup element. The coutput for the colspec elements would be:

   <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="1*" />
   <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="1*" />
   <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="1*" />
   <colspec colnum="1" colname="1" colwidth="1*" />

For the above tgroup element. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm confused why this is in an `<xsl:when>`.  And if `$number` is `4`, then do you want the fourth `colspec` child that has `@colwidth`, or do you just want the fourth `colspec` child?  If the latter, why are you filtering your children with the `@colwidth` predicate?  Is it true that all `colspec` elements will have `@colwidth`?

Comment: Sorry this is confusing. The <xsl:when, is inside of a template that is called. $number is current colspec being processed. I process the tgroup elements. The xml i am processing doesn't necessarily have the same number of colspec elements as there are columns. If so, i generate new ones to match the number of columns. The <xsl:when statement is when there ARE colspecs for each column. If there is a colwidth, i'd like to get that value in the result tree. I DO want the $number colspec, but a colspec may not have a colwidth. I wasn't trying to filter on @colwidth pred, just wanted the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jirka is right ... the attribute isn't being addressed.

But to be more maintainable I would have coded it along the lines of:

```
<xsl:when test="(@cols = count(colspec)) and (colspec[@colwidth][$number])">

  <colspec colnum="{$number}" colname="{$number}" 
           colwidth="{colspec[@colwidth][$number]/@colwidth}"/>
  </colspec>
```

The use of `./` is redundant and cluttering, and the simple value expressions for attributes can be coded with attribute value templates.

Comment: I agree, attribute value templates are much readable and more maintainable. I was too much focused on xpath that I was not thinking about the overall solution and how to make it better.

Comment: Let me also acree, much more readable and cleaner. This also worked!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use this `<xsl:value-of select="./colspec[@colwidth][$number]/@colwidth"/>`. I'm not sure but I think attribute values are not part of string value (which is outputted by value-of).

Comment: This worked! I almost did something like this, but thought it was wrong! Thanks for your help!